# Create vector with only gene names, not logical information

Tags: r

In R I have a Seurat object called "gene counts" and now I want to find all genes with a count=>500. What I have done can be seen in the image but this gives the names of the genes with counts greater than 500 and the logical statement TRUE. How do I change it so that the names are only assigned to the vector and not the TRUE? [image]

**** New ***

[image]

Comment: Maybe `myvector <- gene.counts[gene.counts>=500]`

Comment: `gene.counts[gene.counts>=500]` maybe?

Comment: @DarkShadow, that prints the gene names with their counts. Is this the same as just assigning their names to the vector or is there a way to just give the names as well?

Comment: You can use `myvector <- names(gene.counts[gene.counts>=500])`

Comment: @DarkShadow Yes! Just what I meant! Thank you! Merry christmas and happy new year in advance :)

Comment: @DoraExplorer I will post as solution. You can accept if you want :-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP interaction:

```
myvector <- names(gene.counts[gene.counts>=500])
```

Will solve the issue.